# How to recreate a vmx file?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

As the title says does anyone know how to create a lost vmx file?

The files in which we still have are the associated VMDKs and the log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vmx file simply holds the virtual machine configuration. Simply create a new VM using the vSphere Client and associate your current vmdk files with it.